# "Отменный" - этимология

Tags: этимология

От чего образовано слово "отменный"? Какие у него однокоренные слова?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У слова "отменный" есть устаревшее значение " отличающийся от других, не такой, как другие;особенный", сохраняющееся в диалектах.У Даля есть такие примеры:" Ваш хороший ничем не отменяется от моего худого. Между тем и другим нет никакой отмены, их и не распознаешь." Значит, отменный - различный, несхожий, особенный: У него свои, отменные привычки. Потом у слова "отличный" появилось значение "бесподобный, несравнимый, превосходный, лучший": "отличное настроение"- особенное, замечательное; это значение перешло и на диалектное "отменный" .Было ОТМЕННЫЙ -"отличающийся", стало "отличный" в новом значении-"несравнимый, особенный, замечательный".
Так что образовалось слово от корня с одним значением, а получилось с другим. В современном значении отменный и менять-не однокоренные, а исторически родственные.

Answer (score 1):

Корень мен-, однокоренные слова : смена, замена, перемена. Отменный - отличный от других;  тот, который переменился по сравнению с предыдущими, неважными по качеству предметами и тп.

Comment: почему он пере-менился, а не от-менился?