# Что мы знаем о слове "отменный"?

Tags: лексика

В одной книге, посвященной культурной речи,  автор высказывает недовольство словом "отменный": много у него, дескать,  синонимов (превосходный, прекрасный, первоклассный и др.), для чего нам еще и "отменный".

Зачем активизировали слово, которое "ничего не привносит в нашу речь", зачем "дали ему вторую жизнь".  Наверное, здесь присутствует желание "употребить слово почуднее", а это уже "речевая недисциплинированность"

А что нам вообще известно о двух жизнях слова "отменный"?

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем у классиков.

Зарецкий тридцать два шага отмерил с точностью отменной. Пушкин.

Мягкие кресла, диваны отменные. Некрасов.

В истории известно немало случаев, когда те или иные писатели (иногда филологи, лингвисты) проявляли языковой пуризм, основанный на субъективном восприятии языковых фактов.

Приведу несколько примеров.

Поэт и драматург ХVIIIв. А.П. Сумароков слова предмет, ***обнародовать,*** ***преследовать*** считал непристойными. Известный филолог и журналист ХIХ в.,  редактор реакционный газеты "Северная пчела" жаловался на проникновение слов ***вдохновить, вдохновитель,*** клеймя их как варварские и "беспаспортные". Друг Пушкина поет П.А. вяземский порицал в качестве "площадных выражений" слова ***бездарность*** и ***талантливый***.  Известно, что Толстой не любил слово зря и избегал его в своих произведениях, считая совершенно бессмысленным. Небезызвестный юрист начала ХХ в. П. С. Пороховщиков( П. Сергеич), чья книга "Искусство речи на суде" была переиздана в 1960 г., отвергал такие заимствованные слова, как ***интеллигент***, ***травма*** и др.

К.Федин осуждал слово ***киоскер***, а Б.Лавренев испытывал физическую ненависть к словам ***учеба***( вм. учение) и ***зачитать*** (вм. прочесть или прочитать).  С непримиримой враждебностью относился к слову учеба и Ф.Гладков. Как вспоминает К.Чуковский, с Ф. Гладковым  сделался однажды сердечный припадок, когда его собеседник ( по образованию геолог) вздумал защищать слово учеба ( об истории этого слова и его литературной правомерности в наши дни рассказывается в статье О.Д.Кузнецовой - "Русская речь", 1975,N5).
Примеры взяты из книги  "***Нормы современного русского литературного языка". К.С. М., "Просвещение", 1978. Горбачевич.***

Вера, таких примеров можно приводить много, да и вам, думаю, тоже немало известно.

У слова ***отменный*** не вижу ничего плохого. В словарях он дается без всяких помет. 
Чем больше синонимов у одного слова - тем лучше. Автору, видимо, также не нравится это слово, вот и пишет. А доводы он приводит аргументированные? Кроме тех, что вы здесь привели.

Comment: Серж, спасибо за информацию, пристрастное отношение к словам, конечно, удивительно. Меня же в первую очередь интересует этимология и семантика слова "отменный". Вроде бы автор считает, что у слова ДВА ЗНАЧЕНИЯ - прямое и переносное, а я не очень понимаю ни того, ни другого. Что значит: отменить (уничтожить, упразднить, объявить недействительным) - отменный? И как возникло переносное значение  - "превосходный"?

Comment: Вера, сегодня, согласно словарям у этого слово одно значение. И его можно считать прямым,поскольку никаких других значений у этого слова нет. Все что касается этимологии, автор, видимо, опирался на Даля. Именно в его словаре ( в других - не знаю) встречается это цепочка. Автор считает, что слово отменный произошло от глагола отменить. Но такого значения в словарях нет. У Ефремовой: отменный (устарев). отличный, не похожий на   других.

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://rus.stackexchange.com/a/23077/1826) Вера, почитайте.

Comment: Спасибо Серж, прочитала, только  никак не могу  воспринять на слух эту фразу из Даля: " Ваш хороший ничем не отменяется от моего худого. Между тем и другим нет никакой отмены, их и не распознаешь." Может быть, сам глагол "менять"  (он известен только с 15 века) имел какое-то дополнительное значение, а не только "ты мне это, я тебе то". Может быть, менять - это еще и сравнивать, сличать (иначе как поменяешь) , тогда понятно: отличать - отменять, отличие - отмена.

Answer (score 2):

Страничка из САР со значением слова "отменный" и родственных ему.

> **Отмѣна**, ны. с. ж. 1) Уничтоженiе, отмѣненiе чего. Дѣлать отмѣну какаго постановленiя. Творяху въ нѣкiихъ отмѣны. 3. Макк. III. 3. 2) Качество, свойство отличающее одно лице отъ другаго подобнаго, или одну вещь отъ другой таковойже. Между сими вещами нѣтъ никакой отмѣны. 3) * Предпочтенiе. Дѣлать отмѣну заслуженымъ людямъ.
>
> **Отмѣнный**, ная, ное. Отмѣненъ, нна, нно. прил. 1) Разнствующiй, несходствующiй въ чемъ съ другою вещiю. Эта вещь совершенно отъ другихъ отмѣнна. Образъ жизни его отъ прочихъ во всемъ отмѣненъ. 2) Изящный, предпочтительный, преимущественный. Сдѣлать что съ отмѣннымъ изкуствомъ, раченiемъ. Пользоваться отмѣнною чьею милостiю, довѣренностiю. Я имѣю къ вамъ отмѣнное почтенiе.
>
> **Отмѣнно**. нар. 1) Инако, инымъ образомъ, несходно съ чемъ. Мыслить, разсуждать, вести себя отъ другихъ отмѣнно. 2) Тоже что весьма, чрезвычайно, превозходно. Онъ отмѣнно хорошо, изкусно сочиняетъ. Картина сiя отмѣнно живо написана. Отмѣнность, сти. с. ж. Качество, свойство того, что отмѣнно, отлично отъ чего нибудь; отличность.
>
> **Отмѣнитый**, тая, тое. Отмѣнитъ, та, то. Прил. относящееся къ лицу. Изящными, превозходными дарованiями, добродѣтелями и дѣянiями отличный.
>
> **Отмѣнито**. нар. Изящно, превозходно.
>
> **Отмѣнитость**, сти. с. ж. Качество, состоянiе отмѣнитаго.

Comment: Мне уже кажется, что значение слова "отменный" непосредственно считывается с его морфемного состава. Отменный -  это тот, для которого нет достойной МЕНЫ, РАВНОЙ ему.  Самый близкий синоним - ни с чем не сравнимый, далее - исключительный, неповторимый. Спасибо за внимание, Дерзкий Grantum, навещайте нас почаще.

Comment: @Дерзкий Grantum  Навещайте нас почаще? Но где же вы, интересный автор? Вы не навещаете нас совсем...

Answer (score 1):

Я не исследовал историю употребления этого слова, но, если автор упомянутого высказывания - наш современник, я с ним не могу согласиться. Для меня это слово имеет ясное значение, которое синонимами точно не передать: это нечто изысканно хорошее, хорошо сделанное, не будучи оригинальным или неповторимым. "Отменный борщ" (= приготовленный на редкость хорошо) - самый типичный случай уместного употребления этого эпитета. Понятие же "дисциплины речи" я готов принять, направив его на что-нибудь другое в той же области, например, на канцеляризм "(не)качественный(-но)", или на преодоление такой беды последних лет, как беспорядочное употребление выражения "в том числе".

Comment: А мне кажется, что отменный борщ - это как раз исключительный, необыкновенный и неповторимый.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда у меня появилась такая версия.

1)  Прямое значение слова "отменнй" может использоваться в выражении "отменная грамота" по аналогии с  "жалованной грамотой" .

Например: Псковская судная грамота была принята в 1397 году на городском вече. В числе источников Псковская Судная грамота указывает и грамоту князя Константина, княжившего там в 1407 году.  Причина появления Псковской судной грамоты - ОТМЕНА в 1395 году грамоты Дионисия.

2) Переносное значение слова "отменный" близко к значению "исключительный". исключительный - это   сначала выделяющийся среди обычных  предметов особыми  свойствами, потом - очень хорошими свойствами.

3) Тогда понятно, почему переносное значение  слова "отменный (=отмененный) в значении "превосходный" может вызвать раздражение.

Comment: Немного расширю п.2: отменный значит возвышающийся над рядом сравнимых величин, не допускающий сравнения  и мены на что-то иное.

Comment: А мне кажется, что это СЛЕНГОВОЕ СЛОВЕЧКО, прямого переноса значений нет, а просто вместо исключительный - исключенный кто-то сказал отменный - отмененный. Правда, случилось это давно, в 19 веке слово уже использовалось в обычном порядке.

Comment: Изрядный – не значит исключённый, напротив, он извне и никогда в ряду не стоял, – особенный, противоположность рядовому.

Comment: Я просто хотела сказать, что, возможно,  слово "отменный" НАПРЯМУЮ ЗАИМСТВОВАЛО  свое второе значение у слова "исключительный",

Comment: Просто сказать, что напрямую... И что значит это ключевое слово "исключительный"?

Comment: Исключить -  убрать - отменить, у этих глаголов сходная семантика. Прилагательное исключительный приобретает значение "отличный от других, превосходящий другие, превосходный" и это значение переносится на "отменный". Сначала звучит странно, не очень понятно, а потом становится привычным.  Эта только одна из версий, но другие варианты мне кажутся еще менее правдоподобными.

Comment: Если напрямую, нужно ли было столько слов. Напрямую дорога лежит  через корень.

Comment: Мне кажется,  Вы меня не поняли, несмотря на большое количество слов.  Напрямую - это не развивая собственное переносное значение, а воспользовавшись переносным значением, возникшим у слова "исключительный".

Comment: В общем случае надо бы сопоставлять слова с однотипными конструкциями. Например: отменный-несравненный. Есть ещё слово подходящее — безподобный (стар. орф.)

Answer (score 1):

> Что мы знаем о слове “отменный”?

Из "Объяснительного словаря непроверяемых орфограмм русского языка" (авт. Шелякин М.А., М., 2009):

**ОТМЕНА**, от ***менити*** (менять) + приставка ***-от*** в отрицательном значении = букв. ***не менять***, отсюда ***отменный*** = букв. ***неизменный, хороший.***

Comment: Не очень понятно: отменить - это значить не менять? Это одно и то же? Слияние противоположностей, как в философии? Да и  отменный  как неизменный как-то не очень подходит по смыслу. Может быть, я и ошибаюсь, но мне это объяснение кажется искусственным и надуманным.

Answer (score 0):

""речевая недисциплинированность" - автор явно родом из СССР. Все должны ходить строем и быть дисциплинированными. А слова должны утверждаться на пленуме ЦК КПСС.

Отменный - несхожий - превосходный. Цепочка значений, судя по всему, была такая.